# Can a foreigner easily buy and activate an ALDI talk micro SIM in Germany?

Tags: germany, cellphones, data-plans

I'm going to be traveling through several countries in Europe and I want to get a prepaid data SIM.  I don't use too much data, so I was thinking of getting an ALDI Talk SIM in Germany (where I'll be starting my trip) and using it for the trip.  Their data roaming rates look reasonable as a price to pay to avoid the hassle of buying many SIM cards in different countries if I'm not using too much data.

However, it's not clear to me whether I can easily get ahold of and activate a micro SIM.  I have a Google Nexus 4 which takes micro SIM.  I see some web pages suggesting that the only kind of SIM you can physically buy in an ALDI store is a regular SIM, and that you then have to somehow exchange it.  These pages are a year or two old, though, and since micro SIMs have become more common, I'm not sure whether that info is still valid.  Is it?  Can I go into an ALDI store and walk out with a micro SIM in my hand?

Also, from what I understand, a German address is required to activate the SIM, but its validity isn't checked.  Is this accurate information?  Will I be able to put in my hotel address or something and get it working?

Comment: I am an Engishman living in Germany with my German wife, and it took us over a month to replace an existing Aldi Mobile with a new one.

Answer (score 10):

The answer: Yes, at least in 2013.  I bought the ALDI Talk SIM in Germany in summer 2013.  It was one of those regular SIMs with a detachable micro SIM, so after popping out the micro SIM, it worked fine in my Nexus 4.  I registered with the online form (and some help from Google Translate) and put in my hotel address and it activated fine.

Comment: This is not an answer, but an update to the original question. Please edit your original question to include this information, instead of creating an answer.

Comment: Did you mean to respond to the other answer below?  The question was "can a foreigner use an ALDI Talk SIM card without a German address", and my answer to myself was "Yes, I tried it and it worked."  This is not part of the question.

Comment: What are you people on about? **This is an answer to the question.**

Answer (score 10):

**Oct2018**
I would not recommend this as here is what I went through today and would not get past step 1 without a fluent German and video cell phone access in hand. First have your helper read the included insruction page that the sim is attached to and follow instructions. You need your passport, good video connection, an address in Germany(I used my hotel) and patience...mine took a few hours to process. Also, after you install your sim and get your email from them (wifi access or other email access required)you need to power off and on your phone and enter one of the PIN numbers at the bottom of the instruction sheet. ***The federal law now requires approval of your passport with your presence by video or the Post office. This step happens at the end and takes about 20 mins***

Comment: This should be the **accepted answer**, because ALDI has changed the verification procedure, as of July 1st, 2017.

Answer (score 5):

Registration can be done via an online form, and as far as I've heard it only checks that the address exists.

According to this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jz2Sic7kUAo the Aldi Talk starter set now contains a SIM card that consists of a Micro SIM and a plastic frame.

Comment: There is only a check which verifies the address exists. So technically any address will do. In case you don´t get a micro sim card its very easy to cut a regular one down to micro sim size. Even with crude tools.

Answer (score 3):

Even in 2016 it still works. You just need the telephone number and the SIM card number on the letter glued the sim of the €12.99 starter pack. In the address field, you must put in a valid address consisting of street name, house number, post code, province. Then they ask whether you want to port your old number ignore that. They should have chosen the starter plan for you. Package 600 with 600 MiB and 1.5 GB.

[image: Aldi Talk starter pack]